# The spider (scrapy) does not restart

Tags: scrapy, twisted, restart

I am trying to restart my spider once every 30 minutes, for parsing a website, to which I get an error. The first launch is successful, the next one is an error. Spider Code:

```
def run_spider():
    process1 = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process1.crawl(SpiderCardSpider)

    process1.start()

    time.sleep(18)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        run_spider()
```

Error message:

```
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

I tried to configure thread and much more, at the moment I found the following solution:

```
def run_script_per():
    command = 'cd.. && cd .. && cd card_parc && scrapy crawl spider_card -O results.json'
     subprocess.run(command, shell=True) But I don't think it's good
```

Comment: no :( I have not been able to solve this problem, although I have tried many options

Comment: So you tried to implement it with `CrawlerRunner` and were not able to get it to work?

Comment: Yes, it did’t start